# How can you explain refraction of a single ray of light while entering in denser medium from rarer?

Tags: waves, refraction

We have learned about refraction of light in class. They give a traditional idea about why light bends in the 2nd medium. They take the light beam and make them [it?] incident on glass slab and said " a left rays of beam slow down before the right rays of beam does causing a bend"

Look

[image]

But **what if I incident one SINGLE ray of light?** I know it's practically impossible but still just assume.

Here a single ray will not have any width so we can say that a part of it touches medium first and slow down than other!! It doesn't going to have any part as it's has no or negligible width.

Than **how can you explain  the refraction of a SINGLE ray of light?**

Comment: If you want to remain in the realm of ray optics, you can't _explain_ refraction. You can just quantify it—using Snell's law.

Comment: What do you mean sir?  Can you provide an explanation of my question that " if we take a single ray with very small wavefront and incident on water that there is no question of which part of ray touch water first and slow down as ray is extremely thin to have parts, so here how can you explain bending of ray in water using diagram or idea given in my question?" Please if you can ! Answer It sir!!

Comment: If your ray is thinner than wavelength, it'll expand sideways very fast. It'll basically become a spherical wave—diverging at one side and converging at another—not a ray. You can't get rid of diffraction if you want to work at the level of wave optics.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a single ray of light. They are not countable entities.

Ray optics is an approximation to Maxwell’s equations over length scales that are much larger than the wavelength. So ray optics doesn’t even apply if you have a wavefront that is very small. So even if light rays were countable, you still couldn’t use the ray approximation for a single ray, the approximation itself fails in that case.

Comment: So just SUPPOSE...what if I apply that ideology of slowing down a part of light as in my question on A SINGLE ray (just assume a single ray exist! Can be used here) and incident on slab. Wi it show refraction....because it's wavefront is extremely!!!!! Small. So how we can say one part of it touches first and other later?? The ray should go in same path (no lateral displacement) as it is very small wavefront so it slow down all together unlike one part of it touches the medium first or like that???

Comment: But there are single photons And there’s no way a photon can be slower on one side than the other.

Comment: @SureshChandraPal said “just assume a single ray exist” we can’t do that, as I already explained. The concept of a single ray is incompatible with physics. Since it is incompatible with physics making that assumption means we have to throw out the rest of physics. So how could we then answer your question? Since we already threw away physics to keep your single-ray, what basis do we have for an answer. None. Therefore we have to get rid of the bad assumption. You cannot make a valid conclusion from an invalid assumption

Comment: @Dale that’s silly, all you need to do Take photons and the concept of quantum seriously. Duality can’t be one-sided.

Comment: @BillAlsept a single photon cannot be even remotely approximated as a ray. A single photon takes all possible paths. You have a bad concept of either ray optics or photons or both. Ray optics is an approximation to Maxwell’s equations, which are already inaccurate if you are dealing with a single photon. Ray optics is only valid with many photons and over length scales much larger than a wavelength.

Comment: @Dale so you’re saying a photon going from here to the moon takes every path in every direction across every part of the universe, before it gets there? Yeah right

Comment: @BillAlsept it isn’t me saying it. It is Feynman. https://cosmolearning.org/courses/quantum-electrodynamics-553/video-lectures/ See his lectures on transmission and reflection. He explains the theory and experimental support. A single photon does in fact take all possible paths, just as a single photon goes through both slits. This is how photons behave, regardless of your incredulity

Comment: @Dale Feynman is my hero, no one speaks more about single photons than he does especially in the section about reflections and the mirror. In that section he talks about hundreds of different photons taking every path and in the end some contribute to the image and some don’t but he never says one single photon takes all of those path. Why don’t you explain to me how a single photon can take every path between here and there. By the way I’ve always loved these lectures but I’ve never had them all together like you sent them to me. Thank you

Comment: @BillAlsept If you have a new question then post it as a new question, not as a comment. You should listen to your “hero” more carefully. The path integral is about any quantum field Lagrangian. If you write the Lagrangian for a single photon then the path integral is integrating a single photon over all paths.

Comment: @Dale No, my one question was good enough, I just wish you would have at least tried to answer it. Also point out the exact time in the lecture were Feynman claimed a single photon takes all paths

Comment: @BillAlsept you're looking for [Feynman path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_path_integral).

Comment: @BillAlsept I don’t answer substantial questions in comments, for obvious reasons. Your "hero" explicitly mentions that this formalism applies for a single photon in Corpuscles of Light VI at 8:40 to VII 5:00. It is literally his first concrete example in the series where he first introduces the concept of the arrows that he uses through the rest of the series. So it is explicitly clear from the beginning that he is discussing a formalism which applies to single photon states. You misunderstand him and your claim "he never says one single photon takes all of those path" is wrong

Comment: @Dale now you are twisting things because it was you who said “A Single photon does in fact take all possible paths. You said it in your third comment to me sentence four. You’re trying to backtrack now. I completely understand what Feynman is saying and I agree with it. Individual photons are the best way to derive any quantum phenomena including this question by the op. So back to the OP‘s question. If you don’t believe in single rays, at least now you’re agreeing there are single photons. Single photons refract and therefore can be applied to the OPs question.

Comment: @BillAlsept I am not twisting or backtracking now. A single photon does take all possible paths, that is precisely what Feynman's path integral describes. The total probability amplitude of the photon arriving is the sum (integral) of the amplitudes for each path. Each path has an amplitude and the total amplitude is the sum of all, meaning that each path contributes to the amplitude. So the photon cannot be treated as a single ray traveling along a single path, it doesn't behave that way, as your hero describes quite clearly. If you agree with Feynman then you cannot treat a photon as a ray

Answer (score 1):

The idea of light rays is an abstraction to help describe the general direction of a wavefront of light. They are merely geometrical tools for convenience. Refraction, as taught in classical optics, is a wave property which occurs when the wave encounters a medium with a differing wave propagation speed. The rays that we draw simply aid in visualizing the direction the wave itself is traveling.

Answer (score 0):

The light ray is composed of an electromagnetic field. This can be separated into its electric component and its magnetic nomponent.

You can find the magnetic part using the electric part and some math, so let’s focus on the electric field only.
The electric field is perpendicular to the direction of propagation.

Lets assume that the ray falls on a horizontal surface of some water with an angle.

The direction of the electrical wave can be separated into its tangential part (parallel to the water surface) and the normal part (perpendicular part).

On the air-water boundary, the tangential part is continuous: it does not change (see Maxwell equations). So the « left-to-right » component is the same in air and in water.

The normal part, however, is skewed since it’s not necessarily continuous on the boundary (see Maxwell equations) and the water has a higher refraction index (it “resists” more the wave passing thru).

This being said, when you sum up the normal and the tangential parts of the electrical wave in the water, you see that it is skewed down.

Draw the direction of the light beam, [always] perpendicular to that electrical wave, and you see that it makes an angle.

Here a drawing (own work) :

[image]

(I wrote a whole series of articles on this question, but it’s in French [here](https://couleur-science.eu/?d=dba8dd--pourquoi-la-direction-de-la-lumiere-change-t-elle-quand-elle-penetre-dans-leau). This explanation is also very much based on [this video from Fermi Lab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLmpNM0sgYk))